# How can I change this html code that take value from text-box after enter submit button?

Tags: php, html

I have a text box and a submit button that are connected to html form by event function.

Html code is as below. I would like instead of Pic.jpg, the value of text box select after enter submit button.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://example.com/images/Pic.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

In other word, I want the last part of address which is name of image get value from text box.

Here Is my Submit Button Code in html.

```
<input type="submit" id="Button1" onblur="ShowObject('Html_Form', 1);return false;" name="" value="Lookup" style="position:absolute;width:99px;height:25px;">
```

And textbox html code:

```
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;line-" name="q" value="" placeholder="Enter You Code Here!">
```

Comment: <html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://example.com/images/Pic.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>

You know I have several photos in my Image folder with specific ID. I would like html code show image of the id which i enter in text box.

Comment: need to see the code for the submit action

Comment: Its Submit Button code.
<input type="submit" id="Button1" onblur="ShowObject('Html_Form', 1);return false;" name="" value="Lookup" style="position:absolute;width:99px;height:25px;">

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: you say:
"I have a text box and a submit button that that connected to html form by event function" we need to see how you submit your form, if it's with javascript function than we need to see that function.
Also, provide the html to the page that contains that text box.

Comment: I added required html codes for Submit Button and Text Box.

Comment: So , I am entering my code in Text box and Submit then I want the connected html goes to my image folder in directory and find image as same as code in text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the value from the posted textbox with:

$_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET

```html
<?php

$pic_file_name = $_REQUEST['inputbox'];

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://example.com/images/<?php echo $pic_file_name; ?>"/>
    </body>
</html>
```